# cannot find -lglew for opengl in ubuntu

Tags: opengl, glew

I already installed libglew and the dev
but still cannot find -glew when compiling

```
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglew
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

also I've written in code like

```
#include<GL/glew.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")
```

what should I do next?

Comment: Also `#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")` shall not work unless you're using Microsoft VS compilers.

Comment: `lGlEW` seems to work

Comment: I've posted an answer, if you'd like, please accept it to mark this question solved.

Comment: if you googled here(possible query: cannot find "-lGLEW"), you should probably `sudo apt install libglew-dev`

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know the package `glew` brings libraries named `libGLEW.a` and `libGLEW.so`, so instead of `-lglew` you shall try `-lGLEW`.

Also `#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")` is the way that Microsoft VS compilers do with libraries, and is expected to have no effect with `GNU/Linux` toolchains like `gcc` or `clang`.

Answer (score 0):

If not pathed then just add the full path to the filename of the lib. first make sure that the lib really exists.